# Dask performances: workflow doubts

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm confused about how to get the best from dask.

**The problem**
I have a dataframe which contains several timeseries (every one has its own `key`) and I need to run a function `my_fun` on every each of them. One way to solve it with pandas involves
`df = list(df.groupby("key"))` and then apply `my_fun`
 with multiprocessing. The performances, despite the huge usage of RAM, are pretty good on my machine and terrible on google cloud compute.

On Dask my current workflow is:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get
```

1. Read data from S3. 14 files -> 14 partitions
2. `df.groupby("key").apply(my_fun).to_frame.compute(get=get)

As I didn't set the indices `df.known_divisions` is `False`

The resulting graph is
[image]
and I don't understand if what I see it is a bottleneck or not.

**Questions:**

1. Is it better to have `df.npartitions` as a multiple of `ncpu` or it doesn't matter?
2. From [this](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html?highlight=groupby%20shuffle) it seems that is better to set the index as key. My guess is that I can do something like

   df["key2"] = df["key"]
   df = df.set_index("key2")

but, again, I don't know if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For questions like "what is taking time" in Dask, you are generally recommended to use the ["distributed" scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) rather than multiprocessing - you can run with any number of processes/threads you like, but you have much more information available via the diagnostics dashboard.

For your specific questions, if you are grouping over a column that is not nicely split between partitions and applying anything other than the simple aggregations, you will inevitably need a shuffle. Setting the index does this shuffle for you as a explicit step, or you get the implicit shuffle apparent in your task graph. This is a many-to-many operation, each aggregation tasks needs input from every original partition, hence the bottle-neck. There is no getting around that.

As for number of partitions, yes you can have sub-optimal conditions like 9 partitions on 8 cores (you will calculate 8 tasks, and then perhaps block for the final task on one core while the others are idle); but in general you can depend on dask to make reasonable scheduling decisions so long as you are not using a very small number of partitions. In *many* cases, it will not matter much.

Comment: Am I wrong or the way to use the distributed scheduler is via
`client = Client()` and `df = client.persist(df)`

Comment: That is the simplest way to set up the scheduler, and good for experimentation. You may want to be more explicit with the various parameters and/or have the scheduler out-live your current python session and/or be distributed across several machines, see http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html .